# Regular expression to get Url without Query string

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a way to parse URL without queryString using Regular expression.

i have url like `"http://abc.com/csd?/aaa/bbb"`

expected is like `"http://abc.com/csd"`

Anybody help me on this.

Comment: This is a new or unique kind of regular expression?

Comment: Couldn't you use url.Split('?')[0]

Comment: System.Uri class has methods that will help you in doing such thing without regex.

Comment: Using a regex is probably not the best way to go, unless you're going to expand upon the use. I would simply use String.Substring(...) and String.IndexOf(...) for this. Regex is uber-slow by comparison.

Comment: When you have exact char that is delimiting your string its always better to use string methods. Regular expressions are for more advanced cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want everything before the query string:

```
^[^?]+
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Regex r = new Regex("(^[^?]+)");
Match m = r.Match("http://example.com/csd?/aaa/bbb");
// m.Groups[0].Value is your URL
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Substring` and `IndexOf`

```
var someString = "http://abc.com/csd?/aaa/bbb";
someString.Substring(0, someString.IndexOf('?') - 1);
```

while this does *not* fully comply with the requirements stated in your question, it might be an easier approach - if actual implementation does not need to be RegEx.