# radio-button onchange hyperlink to current url + querystring

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, radio-button, onchange

Im new to javascript and jquery. my website has jquery running.

It want to change css-link using radio-buttons

It has the following radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="css" value="basic" checked>basic
<input type="radio" name="css" value="round" >round
<input type="radio" name="css" value="zoom" >zoom
```

What i need is, when user change radio button, the script should get the current url (eg. http://mysite.com/about.php) and add the selected button value as a query string (eg. http://mysite.com/about.php?css=round) and redirect to that link with query-string.
(if current link has ?css=basic it should change it to ?css=round...)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input:radio").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            window.location.href = "http://mysite.com/about.php" + "?css=" + $(this).val();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search gets you the answers!

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is for binding your function to an event

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) is for the redirect

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript) is to get the current url

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578863/regular-expression-to-get-url-without-query-string) is for getting the url without the query string

and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tag/Regular%20Expressions) helps for figuring out how to use the reg exp

Comment: thanks, this is what i needed, but Im struggling to put them alltogether. Pl. Help me little more...